# How to add logic into a Backspace key press event in Textbox of FabricJS?

Tags: fabricjs

Basically what I'm looking for is how to add my own logic to the keyPress event... I mean I need to check something before deleting some char from a Textbox element.
I've managed to add "catch" event, but now nothing deletes from Textbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/redlive/n2x5k3Ld/

```js
fabric.Textbox.prototype.onBackspacePressed = function(e) {
    console.log('____xxx', this, e);
    //e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
    //e.preventDefault();
};

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');
canvas.setHeight(300);
canvas.setWidth(500);

var text = new fabric.Textbox('Hello beautiful world', {
  left: 50,
  top: 10,
  fontFamily: 'arial',
  fill: '#333',
  fontSize: 50
});

text.keysMap = fabric.util.object.clone(text.keysMap);
text.keysMap['8'] = 'onBackspacePressed';
            
canvas.add(text);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="paper" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found a way to control Backspace.

```
fabric.Textbox.prototype.onBackspacePressed = function(e) {
    if (1===1) { // Add your condition here
        this.removeChars(e);
    }
};
```

Works fine.

Comment: Yes this is mostly the right thing to do. It's ok and is a correct way to extend functionality. Is also true is not written anywhere in the docs